# Python3 opening different files in current directory from list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a weird ask for an automation script im trying to use to learn a bit more python. Basically what im trying to do is get python to read the directory the python script is in (im hoping eventually to turn it into an EXE) to find all CSV files using:

```
os.listdir("./")
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
    FileName.append(file)  # FileName is defined a blank list at the top
```

This then appends all CSV names to a list, im then using:

```
with open(filename, newline='') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
doStuff()
```

This works to open the variable filename i have defined before use, ive tested that and all seems to work. What i need to be able to do is have python iterate through the list it creates and run the same code for each file. so i need to do something like:

```
with open(for FN in FileName: doStuffBelow(), newline='') as f:
```

this obviously doesn't work, just wondering if i can take each item in the list, make it run the functions below that then loop back until the end. Any help appreciated :). Also the list length is variable depending on how many CSV files have been generated so i cant even pre-define a bunch of variables in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
for i in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(i, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            doStuff()
```

Or if you want to put the files into a list first:

```
csv_files = []
for i in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        csv_files.append(i)

for i in csv_files:
    with open(i, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        doStuff()
```

Comment: Wow I'm going to take the tard award. I should have worked that out .. thanks man you are a legend